# JavaScript: Search string from position

Tags: javascript, regex, string

JavaScript has two useful methods, both which *nearly* do what I need.

- `String.prototype.indexOf()` will search for a substring and return its position. It has an optional `position` parameter which is the starting point of the search, so you can easily find the next one.
- `String.prototype.search()` will search a string using a regular expression and return its position. However, as far as I can tell, it *doesn’t* allow a starting position, so it always searches from the start.

Is there anything which allows me to find the position using a regular expression which *does* allow for a starting position?

Comment: You need this for a specific pattern only, or for "dynamic" ones? If the former - you could simply "prefix" it with `^[^]{x}`, `x` being the number of characters you want to "skip".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do a [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) in advance to get rid of unwanted parts and then take [`String#search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search).

```
function search(string, regexp, from = 0) {
    const index = string.slice(from).search(regexp);
    return index === -1
        ? -1
        : index + from;
}
```

Comment: But doesn't that mean, the actual position of the substring we are looking for will always be at `position - the_chars_removed_from_the_start`?

Comment: @Behemoth, you need to att the returnd pos to the removed substring length.

Comment: OK, something like `string.slice(pos).search(substring)+pos` ?

Comment: @Manngo, you need to keep `-1` if returned.

Comment: Disadvantage: If this is done inside a loop which loops over a string in linear time and your JS compiler makes `String#slice` return a copy every time (rather than a mere view into the string) this may run in quadratic time.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course. Two steps, then: `var index = string.slice(pos).search(substring); index = index>=0 ? index+pos : -1;`.

Answer (score 2):

[The other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73191185/316310) is the way to go as its much clearer what the intention is, but if you *had to use* a regular expression, you could do it like this:

```
// This string should not include characters that have special
// meaning in regular expressions / should be escaped.
const inputString = "foo bar baz bar";
const offset = 8;
const searchString = "bar";
inputString.search(new RegExp(`(?=.{${offset}}${searchString}`));

//  (?=             make sure ${searchString} ("bar") 
//                  is preceded by:
//  .               anything
//  {$(a number)}   at least this many times:
//                  {8} in this example.

// The (?=A)B positive lookahead won't be included in the result,
// so you don't need to plus or minus the offset from the result:

// Example:
const str = 'aabbcc aabbcc aabbcc';
               ^      ^      ^
               2      9      16

str.search(new RegExp(`(?<=.{${0}})bb`));
// Return 2

str.search(new RegExp(`(?<=.{${4}})bb`));
// Returns 9

str.search(new RegExp(`(?<=.{${10}})bb`));
// Returns 16

str.search(new RegExp(`(?<=.{${1000}})bb`));
// Returns -1

str.search(new RegExp(`(?<=.{${10}})doesntexist`));
// Returns -1
```

Comment: Downside of this approach is that it incurs the cost of RegEx compilation each time.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the position of the original position of the search result you could use [Nina Scholz' approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73191185/12834972) and then re-add the characters removed from the start. For Instance:

```js
const str = "Hello World!";
let start = 5;
const output = str.substring(start).search(/World/g) + start;
console.log(output); //6
```

Note: Be careful with cases where `.search()` returns `-1`.